# using Web Service with Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

In past I have been able to add web service through Visual Studio adding Service Reference.

Now I need to use WSDL which using basic authentication. When I trying add new service reference I'm getting error `The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'BASIC realm="owsm"'.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.`

Where I can change authentication or add credentials for creating new service reference?

Comment: Add the service using an offline wsdl and reconfigure with authentication and live url later could work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do. First right click your solution in solution explorer and click 'Add service reference'

[image]

Then Click 'Advanced'

[image]

Then click 'Add Web Reference'

[image]

That should do it.

Comment: Why would "Add Web Reference" help? That's a legacy technology, and generally should not be used for new development.

Comment: In other words, there has to be a good reason to fall back to a web reference, and you have not supplied a good reason. Please supply a good reason, and please say why you believe that will solve his problem. This is especially important since it's not clear from the question exactly what the problem actually _is_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders What's the recommended way of doing that without resorting to legacy technologies?

Comment: I don't know. For example if you are connecting to the CrmService with Crm 4.0 I have not found a way to make it work unless I follow the steps above